# Homestead not installed properly

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

when I install Homestead by using `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` and call `homestead` I miss all the commands that should be available. Never happened before. Did something chance in the process of installation?

[image]

Comment: Any chance you skipped or changed any of installation steps for any reason?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is step by step setup procedure with explanation.

This is might be what you are looking for:

[Laravel Homestead with Windows 10 Step by Step setup procedure with explanation](https://medium.com/@eaimanshoshi/i-am-going-to-write-down-step-by-step-procedure-to-setup-homestead-for-laravel-5-2-17491a423aa)

I worked and tested it.